# Struggling with Apache

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

Good evening all,

I am a new linux user, and i have a ubuntu Server in a rack at my house. I am attempting to install Multicraft on it, i followed the instructions of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=758vK7wfQug.

Basically it instructed me to create a lamp server. I did as follows. I confirmed that Apache is functioning correctly by going to the lan address of the server, and i was able to access phpmyadmin by typing 192.168.1.8/phpmyadmin. Here is where it gets sticky. When i type 192.168.1.8/multicraft to access the control panel to finalize the installation i get this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /multicraft was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.8 Port 80
```

Everything ive seen from the tutorials and such says this should be working but for some reason its not.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Papabear

Comment: Just a friendly tip: You should proofread your question first.  "Apatche" and "Unbuntu" make it sound like you haven't done your homework.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this setup running within a virtual machine. Granted, I have no idea how to connect to it, etc. since I'm no Minecraft player. However, it seemed to install successfully.

The reason you don't have /var/www/multicraft is that you did not run the installer as 'sudo'. Since you weren't UID/GID www-data, the files weren't able to be created within /var/www. However, there were a couple other quirks I encountered while doing this so I'm going to provide you a guide so that you don't run into any more pitfalls (at least upto and including installation).

So, here's my step-by-step intro to how to get this up and running (tested in a 14.04 Server VM).

1. Run the multicraft installer: `sudo ./install.sh`
2. All default settings should be fine.
3. You now have the files in /var/www/multicraft, however we have to make a few more changes to get the installer to complete.
4. Next, there are a couple of requirements for working with sqlite databases and enabling capchas (if applicable). php5-sqlite is, of course for sqlite and php5-gd is for the capchas. `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite php5-gd`
5. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
6. In Trusty, there is no <Directory> entry and the default folder is /var/www/html instead of /var/www.
7. Change DocumentRoot to /var/www if it's not already
8. Add the following <Directory> entry below CustomLog to ensure the protected directory's .htaccess file gets parsed properly:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/multicraft>
     AllowOveride all
   </Directory>
   ```

   This tells Apache to parse the .htaccess file in /var/www/multicraft and all sub-folders.
9. Then, restart apache to apply the changes: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
10. Now you should be able to navigate to `http://[IP]/multicraft/install.php` to do the installation.
11. After installation, run the daemon like this: 'sudo /home/minecraft/multicraft/bin/multicraft -v start'
12. There is no auto-start functionality for this program, so you may look into making your own init script in /etc/init.d (see /etc/init.d/skeleton and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Init_scripts)) (NOTE: I'm not advocating making an Upstart job due to Canonical's recent announcement planning to scrap Upstart for systemd in the future.)

Comment: Thank you for putting so much time into helping me resolve my issue, it is fixed and working and everything is good to go (knock on wood).